# Foreach Loop not passing all values as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through an array comprised of IP addresses collected from a text file. The ultimate goal of this is to retrieve the host name for each IP. My problem is I am only getting results from the last IP in the array. I figured it would be pretty simple, but I am clearly missing something.

```
<?php
$thefile = 'myfile';
$arr = file($thefile.".txt");

foreach ($arr as $data) {
echo $hostname = gethostbyaddr($data);" <br>";
?>
```

The text file contains several IP's that I know have associated names, but I get

"Warning: gethostbyaddr() [function.gethostbyaddr]: Address is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address in..."
 for every instance but the last, which returns the correct results. Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you print out the `$data` variable without using your `gethostbyaddr()` function does it appear as you expect?

Comment: Yes, I will actually be including that as a part of my code to link the hostname with the IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$thefile = 'myfile';
$arr = file($thefile . '.txt',FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach ($arr as $data) 
{
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr(trim($data));
    echo $hostname . "<br>";
}

?>
```

You likely have a newline or some whitespace, so use [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove them before passing to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file is fine, and looks like this:

```
    100.100.100.100
    100.100.100.101
    100.100.100.102
```

Per the PHP manual for `file`: "Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, **with the newline still attached**."

You'll need to strip those newlines out, using [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) should do the trick.

Comment: That was just what I needed to do, thanks for the fast response.